# Which language uses .pde extension?

Tags: processing, file-extension

While searching for an implementation of the Barnsley's Fern fractal I came across a implementation that has .pde extension. Which programming language uses this extension?

[Implementation Page](http://www.openprocessing.org/visuals/?visualID=198)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This code is from Processing.org an open source Java based IDE. You can find it [Processing.org](http://processing.org). The Arduino IDE also uses this extension, although they run on a hardware board.

**EDIT** - And yes it is C syntax, used mostly for art or live media presentations.

Comment: Well, it's C syntax, not based.

Comment: Current versions of Arduino switched to .ino extensions.  see https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Comparison. They say: "The Arduino language (based on Wiring) is implemented in C/C++, and therefore has some differences from the Processing language, which is based on Java." The switch is since version 1.0 as noted in https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Environment: "NB: Versions of the Arduino Software (IDE) prior to 1.0 saved sketches with the extension .pde. It is possible to open these files with version 1.0, you will be prompted to save the sketch with the .ino extension on save."

Answer (score 32):

The .pde file extension is the one used by the [Processing](http://processing.org/), [Wiring](http://wiring.org.co/), and the [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) IDE.

Processing is not C-based but rather Java-based and with a syntax derived from Java. It is a Java framework that can be used as a Java library. It includes a default IDE that uses .pde extension. Just wanted to rectify @kersny's answer.

Wiring is a microcontroller that uses the same IDE. Arduino uses a modified version, but also with .pde. The OpenProcessing page where you found it is a website to exhibit some Processing work.

If you know Java, it should be fairly easy to convert the Processing code to Java AWT.

Answer (score 9):

Bad news I'm afraid (or maybe great news?) :  it isn't C code, it's an example of "Processing" - an open source language aimed at programming images. Take a look [here](http://www.processing.org/)

Looks very cool.

Answer (score 5):

pde is extesion for:

- Processing: Java derived language
- Wiring: C/C++ derived language (Wiring is derived from Processing)
- Early versions of Arduino: C/C++ derived  (Arduino IDE is derived from Wiring)

For Arduino for example the IDE preprocessor is adding some #defines and some C/C++ files before giving all to gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Software application written with Arduino, an IDE used for prototyping electronics; contains source code written in the Arduino programming language; enables developers to control the electronics on an Arduino circuit board.

To avoid file association conflicts with the Processing software, Arduino changed the Sketch file extension to .INO with the version 1.0 release. Therefore, while Arduino can still open ".pde" files, the ".ino" file extension should be used instead.

Each PDE file is stored in its own folder when saved from the Processing IDE. It is saved with any other program assets, such as images. The project folder and PDE filename prefix have the same name. When the PDE file is run, it is opened in a Java display window, which renders and runs the resulting program.

Processing is commonly used in educational settings for teaching basic programming skills in a visual environment.